# iCloud Tab Sync is not Working

Tags: icloud, safari

Safari tabs sync is not working on my three iCloud devices - macOS (11.0.1), iPad (14.2), and iPhone (14.2).
The sync issue is among all devices, so the iPad can't see iPhone open tabs, iPhone isn't synced with the mac's open tabs, and so on.

The expected behavior is that every new open tab in one device appears in the other device's safari browser. The actual behavior is that tabs are not synced at all or only after a few hours.

I've already logout and login from iCloud on all devices and cleared the browsing cache.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem... I thought it was just on my mac, but when I went to check I'm not seeing icloud tabs on my phone either. I was for a time even when the mac wasn't working.

Comment: Ok so 3 hours later and I can see my mac and iPad tabs on my phone but not any tabs (besides the local tabs) on my Mac.